# Ruled surface by skinning

Tags: numerical-methods

I have the following problem. I have one curve and the article I am analyzing says: we can generate a ruled surface by skinning the curve in a direction D. I don't know how I can obtain a ruled surface by a process of skinning one single curve. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminology used in the article is pretty strange.

Usually "skinning" means creation of a surface that passes through a given set of roughly parallel curves.

A "ruled surface" is a special case: the case where you have only two curves. You then create a surface by joining corresponding points on the two curves with straight lines. The straight lines are called the "rulings" of the surface.

If you only have one curve, and you sweep it along a direction vector, D, then most people would call this an "extruded" surface. Alternatively, the very old term is "tabcyl".

If your CAD system has a "skin" command, but no "extrude" command, then you need to create a second curve from the first one. Just translate your curve by a vector D to get the second one. Then you can do skinning using these two curves.

In mathematical terms, if the given curve is $C(u)$ then the extruded surface is
$$
S(u,v) = C(u) + vD
$$